# Does return stop a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, return

If I have the following `for` loop

```
    for (var i = 0; i < SomeArrayOfObject.length; i++) {
    
      if (SomeArray[i].SomeValue === SomeCondition) {

         var SomeVar = SomeArray[i].SomeProperty;
         return SomeVar;
      }
    }
```

Does the `return` statement stop the function's execution?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Yes, functions always end whenever their control flow meets a `return` statement.

The following example demonstrates how `return` statements end a function’s execution.

```js
function returnMe() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i === 1) return i;
  }
}

console.log(returnMe());
```

Notes: See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714537/3991403) about the special case of `try`–`catch`–`finally` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function/34653650) about how the `forEach` callback has its own function scope, so it will not break out of the containing function.

Comment: > return always exits its function immediately, with no further execution if it's inside a loop
[...unless it's a forEach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function/34653650)

Comment: @o-o Sort of true. `return` still returns from the current iteration of the function callback, in its own scope, but would not be expected to break from the entire calling method `forEach()`. So it isn't returning from the _loop itself_, but it is returning from the callback the loop executes.  In the code example from the linked question, the output is `1,2,4,5` skipping the `3` because of the return.

Comment: Maybe the red thread is that `return`will always return from the current `this` context.

Comment: The alternative to using forEach() or for() on an array for “potentially” early loop termination is using some().

Comment: I know this is trivial for some people, but this is so good know because you no longer have to `break` and then `return`.

Answer (score 89):

In **most** cases (including this one), `return` will exit immediately.  However, if the return is in a `try` block with an accompanying `finally` block, the `finally` always executes and can "override" the `return` in the `try`.

```
function foo() {
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                return i; // This executes once
            }
        }
    } finally {
        return 42; // But this still executes
    }
}

console.log(foo()); // Prints 42
```

Comment: Amazing solution, Yes return will always execute in that case use try catch

Answer (score 26):

This code will exit the loop after the first iteration in a `for of` loop:

```
const objc = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 3 }];
for (const iterator of objc) {
  if (iterator.name == 2) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(iterator.name);// 1
}
```

the below code will jump on the condition and continue on a `for of` loop:

```
const objc = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 3 }];

for (const iterator of objc) {
  if (iterator.name == 2) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(iterator.name); // 1  , 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot, i'm using node and the return is breaking my for, for each and for...of, the continue works like i expected

Answer (score 17):

The `return` statement stops a loop only if it's inside the function (i.e. it terminates both the loop and the function). Otherwise, you will get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement(…)
```

To terminate a loop you should use `break`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, once the `return` statement is executed, the entire function is exited at that very point.

Just imagine what would happen if it did not and continued looping, and executing that `return` statement each time? It would invalidate it's meaning of returning a value when you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, if you write return statement the controls goes back to to the caller method immediately. 
With an exception of finally block, which gets executed after the return statement.

and finally can also override the value you have returned, if you return inside of finally block.
LINK: [Try-catch-finally-return clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification)

Return Statement definition as per:

Java Docs:

> a return statement can be used to branch out of a control flow block
>   and exit the method

MSDN Documentation:

> The return statement **terminates the execution of a function** and
>   returns control to the calling function. Execution resumes in the
>   calling function at the point immediately following the call.

Wikipedia:

> A return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine
>   and resume at the point in the code immediately after where the
>   subroutine was called, known as its return address. The return address
>   is saved, usually on the process's call stack, as part of the
>   operation of making the subroutine call. Return statements in many
>   languages allow a function to specify a return value to be passed back
>   to the code that called the function.

Comment: You need to properly link the sources you used, and ideally format the quotes as well.

Comment: does that look fine now?

Comment: I appreciate the grammar fixes, but there still aren't any links, and you're still not using blockquote formatting.

Answer (score 0):

"return" does exit the function but if you want to return large sums of data, you can store it in an array and then return it instead of trying to returning each piece of data 1 by 1 in the loop.