# Confused execution in try with return value in java

Tags: java, android, return, try-catch

I have run and debugged this java code in Android and I have noticed that the `return true` has no effect because it act as a `break` and then the `return false` is finally executed. I have used the Android Studio and its Step Over function for debugging.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
   // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
   mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
   // Start connection attempt
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      try {
         // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
         // until it succeeds or throws an exception
         mmSocket.connect();
         // connection successful [it should return true]
         return true;
      }
      catch (IOException connectException) {
         // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
         try { mmSocket.close(); }
         catch (IOException closeException) {  }
      }
   }
   // connection failed 10 times [but it always returns false]
   return false;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Like EJP and others say, `return true` does not act as a break. The `doInBackground` function runs as expected. The problem was that, the AsyncTask was always cancelled just after the execution of `return true` because of a external code block. I'm sorry about that.

This post can be closed. Thank you.

Comment: If you write a return in For it always acts as a break.  plus even if some exception occurs in your connection you are just catching it and not returning after that. Why do you want to put your connect statement in a for loop. even if you want to ensure that it keeps on trying until you connect, do it in a do while loop and check in while if the connection is established successfully.

Comment: it is not very good programming because I use the return statement inside a loop and this would cause garbage collection to malfunction.

Comment: @FadySaad No, it wouldn't cause garbage collection to malfunction. Can't imagine where you got that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have run and debugged this java code in Android and I have noticed that the return true has no effect

Only if there was an exception. Ten exceptions.

> because it act as a break

No it doesn't.

> and then the return false is finally executed.

No it doesn't. The only way the final `return` can be reached is if there were ten exceptions.

*Ergo* there *was* an exception. Ten exceptions. The first one was a `ConnectException`, and the ones after that all related to your invalid attempt to reconnect the same socket instead of creating a new one first.

Trace the exceptions and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no exception? from your code, it will returns true if there is not problem with *.connect* method, try to log your exception to check whatever the connection is successful.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: With this code you can't know if an exception is thrown or not.

Comment: And this is the answer, you need to make sure that the connection is successful before checking the code flow.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an exception occuring, the `return true` will not take effect. Why `false` returned, because the exception was caught silently.

I can give you a sample code here,

```
private static void connect() throws Exception
{
    throw new Exception();
}

private static Boolean doInBack() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            if (i % 7 != 0 || i == 0)
                continue;
            connect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");

        }
    }

    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print(doInBack());

}
```

---

A reference about the [try-catch-finally-return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification) execution order.

Comment: Everyone can downvote  others only if he/she gives a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what EJP said, your code inside the try-catch is failing 10x, not because the `return true` is not behaving the way you expected it. And when it fails 10x, as it should, you end up at `return false`.

You *need* to log your `connectException` and `closeException`, at least with something like `e.printStackTrace`.

Also, don't let multiple `return`'s short sight you. Try it like this:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
   ...
   boolean success = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      try {
         ...
         mmSocket.connect();
         success = true;
      } catch (IOException connectException) {
         ...
      }
   }
   return success;
}
```

if `connect()` succeeds, then `success = true`, otherwise `success` will stay `false`. (now there's no doubt over your confusion on why a return is acting like a break)

As a side note, yes, without more context here, you may need to consider that if the first `connect()` fails, then it is possible that all subsequent connects will too.