# Python context-manager decorator masks my exception?

Tags: python, exception, decorator, contextmanager

Following the examples in https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html ..

In the synthetic code below:

```py
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager, nullcontext


class MyException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, *args: object) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args)


@contextmanager
def annotate():
    try:
        yield None
    finally:
        return


def annotate2():
    return nullcontext()


def main():
    try:
        with annotate():
            raise MyException()

    except MyException:
        print("Good, Caught exception")
        sys.exit(0)

    print("How did I get here ???")
    sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The exception is not caught.
But if I change it to

```py
 with annotate2():
            raise MyException()
```

Then it works as expected.
My question is, what is wrong with my contextmanager ?

```py
@contextmanager
def annotate():
    try:
        yield None
    finally:
        return
```

(Tested with python 3.10.4)

Thanks

Boaz

Comment: Yes, I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, found the answer in
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

> If the finally clause executes a break, continue or return statement, exceptions are not re-raised.