# What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
$('button').click(function () {
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function (n) {
      if (n == 3) {
         // it should break out here and doesn't alert anything after
         return false
      }
      alert(n)      
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

My question: Why does it still alert next number although I call `return`? Just like: *Ignore the code below and continue with next element*

Comment: What about `$('button').click(function(){})`?

Comment: You can break it using `if(n>=3){ return false`

Comment: `return` doesn't break a loop, the `break` does!

Comment: Interestingly the behavior of the example is much different if you alter line 2 and assign the array to a variable first like: `var r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; r.forEach(function (n) {`. In this case it will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description):

> There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the `forEach()` method is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> - A simple loop
> - A [`for`...`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
>     loop
> - [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
> - [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
> - [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
> - [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
>
> The other Array methods: [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) test the array elements with a predicate returning a truthy value to determine if further iteration is required.

Comment: Using `forEach`, and trowing an error to stop the iteration is a very bad practice, and is a real overkill. In your case you don't really want to iterate **all** of the array (forEach...), but you want to run until certain statement is met. You should use a simple loop for it (`while`, `for`, `for in`, `do while`).

Comment: I agree with @RonenCypis ... And suggest you to use `some()`

Comment: Everybody's got a plan until `new Array(5)` shows up.... `(new Array(5)).every(e => e === "maybe for loop + break wasn't such a bad idea after all?")` produces surprising results due to sparse arrays.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of what `return` actually does in practice for a `forEach` loop, but I guess the next answer helps.

Answer (score 60):

The `return` exits the **current** function, but the iterations keeps on, so you get the "next" item that skips the `if` and alerts the 4...

If you need to stop the looping, you should just use a plain `for` loop like so:

```
$('button').click(function () {
   var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var n = arr[i]; 
     if (n == 3) {
         break;
      }
      alert(n);
   })
})
```

You can read more about js break & continue here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: What do you mean??? I wrote it like that for the ease of understanding... The code could be shortened a bit maybe, but it gets exactly what you wanted, without extra iterations of the array like some other answers here :-)

Comment: You need to declare array before. You want to use a loop within the array length. You need an index to access array element..... So many things :) That's I mean

Comment: you've already declared the array in your example, i just added a reference (var arr) to it for easy access. You can also change the `for` loop to `for in`, or `while`... all of those options are much better, and faster then creating a new function, and throwing an error in your other examples here. Both performance wise, and clean-code... good luck anyway :-)

Comment: This answer cleared up my exact question about whether it still sometimes makes sense to return inside a `forEach` loop, which it absolutely does when you don't want the remainder of your loop logic to be executed given a certain condition!

Comment: Original code has alert on 1,2,4,5. It misses 3. - 10 feb 2022 -firefox 97.

Comment: So basically return statement doesn't do anything except for that specific condition n==3. Not cool behavior.