# How to write the Array.prototype.every() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, predicate

As practice, I want to write a function all() that works similar to the Array.prototype.every() method. This function returns true only if the predicate supplied returns true for all the items in the array.

```
Array.prototype.all = function (p) {
  this.forEach(function (elem) {
    if (!p(elem)) 
      return false;
  });
  return true;
};

function isGreaterThanZero (num) {
  return num > 0;
}

console.log([-1, 0, 2].all(isGreaterThanZero)); // should return false because -1 and 0 are not greater than 0
```

Somehow this doesn't work and returns `true`. What's wrong with my code? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Comment: You might find this link interesting http://reactivex.io/learnrx/ And take a look at libraries like lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4

Comment: If you look at your console, you'll see that you get nothing for -1, true for 0, and true for 2. You're not killing the loop when it returns false. You can't kill the loop with a forEach because it's specifically for running through each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only stop a `forEach()` loop by throwing an exception. Just use a normal `for` loop instead.

```
Array.prototype.all = function (p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(!p(this[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

If any method other than `Array.prototype.every()` is allowed to be used, then you can:

```
Array.prototype.all = function (p) {
  return this.filter(p).length == this.length;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't break out of an [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop by returning. Use a for loop instead.

**Note:** This is a partial implementation of [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to demonstrate the return issue.

```js
Array.prototype.all = function (p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(!p(this[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
};

function isGreaterThanZero (num) {
  return num > 0;
}

console.log([-1, 0, 2].all(isGreaterThanZero));
```

Answer (score 0):

return in foreach function is not returning value from your function. You can code like this.

```
        Array.prototype.all = function (p) {
            for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
                if (!p(this[i])) 
                    return false;
            }                
            return true;
        };

        function isGreaterThanZero (num) {
            return num > 0;
        }

        var result = [2, 3, 4].all(isGreaterThanZero);
        console.log("result", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are slightly wrong. The callback you pass in should be called with 3 arguments: the current item, the index, and the entire array. This is how the native `Array.every`, and indeed most native array functions, work. Your callback can choose to use these arguments but most of the time it doesn't.

```js
Array.prototype.all = function (p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (!p(this[i], i, this)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};

function isGreaterThanZero (num) {
  return num > 0;
}

console.log([-1, 0, 2].all(isGreaterThanZero)); // should return false because -1 and 0 are not greater than 0
```

Comment: If you're going for the full Array#every implementation, don't forget to add the [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).