# filtering on arrays in arrays, is there an elegant way of doing this?

Tags: javascript

This one has always served me well...

```
var myProperty = "FOO"

var expenseSelect = expenseArray.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.property == myProperty
});
```

But now I have a situation where the obj.property is an array of properties ["FOO", "BAR", "WEE"] inside the expenseArray.

Is there a smart way to do this? Or do I have to do the whole loop inside loop thing?

Comment: Recursion ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796948/search-a-deeply-nested-value-in-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: There's no intrinsic mechanism for comparing arrays (or objects) based on content, so yes it's up to you to implement the comparison somehow.

Comment: Not sure, if I understood correctly, but shouldn't this work: `expenseArray.filter((obj) => obj.property.includes( myProperty ) )` ?

Comment: `expenseArray.filter(obj => obj.property.includes(myProperty))`

Comment: `obj.property` is an array of ***values***…?!

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ nice one!!! Didnt think that was possible hehe.  A bit hackery but Im gonna try it out :)

Comment: Hmmm includes might just do it yes, that would be an easy solution - testing it and writing back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if myProperty is in the array you can do it using

```js
var myProperty = "FOO"

var expenseSelect = expenseArray.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.property.includes(myProperty);
});
```

Comment: Marvel that did the trick! very elegant and simple, like it!!

Answer (score 0):

using the [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method tests whether at-least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function, it can be a simple an option..

```js
var myProperty = "FOO";
var expenseArray=[];
expenseArray[0]={ property: ["FOO", "BAR", "WEE"] };
expenseArray[1]={ property: ["NoFOO", "BAR", "WEE"]} ;

var expenseSelect = expenseArray.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.property.some(function(element,index,array){
      return element == myProperty;
    });
});

console.log(expenseSelect);
```