# return true actually returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Heres my code.
I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

```
var arr = [{
   order_count: 1,
   order_date: "2015-10-10"

}, {
    order_count: 2,
    order_date: "2017-03-01"
}, {
    order_count: 3,
    order_date: '2017-04-10'
}];

function checkDay (date, maxDays){
   var flag = false;
   arr.forEach(function(element) {
     if (element.order_date === date && element.order_count >= maxDays)
     {
      flag = true;
      return true;
     }
   });
   if (!flag) {
    return false;
   }
}

console.log(checkDay('2017-04-10', 3));
```

Comment: because `checkDay` doesn't return anything when flag is true ... just `return flag` ... oh, and `return true` in forEach does not stop the forEach ... perhaps you want to look at array methods like `.some` or `.every` for loops that **can** terminate early

Comment: You really should be using some() not forEach()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function/34653650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array.some method

```
function checkDay(date, maxDays) {
    return arr.some(element => element.order_date === date && element.order_count >= maxDays);
}
```

This will only loop until either all elements are processed and evaluated `false`, or finish looping once a `true` is returned - so, the behaviour is exactly as you expected

Answer (score 3):

The `return true` inside your `arr.forEach` only breaks out of the current iteration inside the `forEach` (other iterations will continue to be executed), not the main function.

Change

```
if (!flag) {
 return false;
}
```

to

```
return flag;
```

Comment: Your statement is not right, there is NO way to break out of a forEach other than throwing an error.

Comment: It doesn't break the entire forEach, it just breaks the current iteration.

Comment: Clarified this.

Answer (score 0):

**You're not returning a value**

```
function checkDay (date, maxDays) {
   var flag = false;

   arr.forEach(function(element) {
     if (element.order_date === date && element.order_count >= maxDays) {
      flag = true;
     }
   });

   return flag;
}
```

**A better approach using the function `some`**

```
function checkDay (date, maxDays) {
  return arr.some((element) => element.order_date === date && element.order_count >= maxDays);       
}
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

  > The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.