# return statement inside foreach always return undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am stuck with some of concepts in forEach. Referred some of sites to clear my thought about why **return** inside forEach always returns **undefined** where map, find statements returns the values but not getting correct idea. anyone please redirect me to correct websites if there or please clear my doubt.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not clear what your asking, Array.forEach() returns undefined by design (what else would it return?)

Comment: my doubt is not code related i am working. But always i want to return a specific thing from an array conditionally, return statement results undefined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically when you use forEach you say that you want to a particular thing for every element, note that to accomplish that task **you dont need to return anything** and even if you do, just think what use will it be ?

but when you `map` you want every element to be converted to something, now **this something has to be the return value** of the function inside `map`

Comment: thanks for your information