# Matching two dates - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problems with task which looks like pretty simply. I need to match two variables and return true if match and false if not.

I have made method which check it

```
    isAnyApplicationFromToday(): boolean {
      this.userApplications.forEach(application => {
        if (application.registerDate.toString() == this.today.toString()) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    return false;
  }
```

but it always return false.

Funny is that, if I console.log(), variable values match.

I tried already combination:

```
if (application.registerDate.toString() === this.today.toString())
if (application.registerDate === this.today)
if (application.registerDate == this.today)
```

[image]

any ideas ?

EDIT:

```
  isAnyApplicationFromToday(): boolean {
    let isAny = false;
      this.userApplications.forEach(application => {
        if (application.registerDate.toString() === this.today.toString()) {
          isAny = true;
        }
      });
    return isAny;
  }
```

work just fine.

Comment: I suggest you to use timestamp. Convert date into timestamp and then compare.

Comment: But how I will comare if timestamp is from same day ?

Comment: The problem is you are returning inside the `forEach`, instead of the main function
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function

Comment: The `forEach` takes in a function. You're example is taking a function that returns true. This has no effect on the outer function.

What you intend is for the outer function `isAnyApplicationFromToday` to return the result of the innerfunction. I suggest you do something like this:

    isAnyApplicationFromToday(): boolean {
        var result = false;
        this.userApplications.forEach(application => {
            result = application.registerDate.toString() == this.today.toString();
        });
        return result;
    }

Comment: Guys You're right !!