# TypeScript wait for promise.all and return result

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, async-await

I am writing some code in Node.Js, and use promise.all for parallel executing. To simplify the issue I use following sample code

in MyService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private readonly anotherService: AnotherService) { }

    public async job1(a: number): Promise<MyObject> {
        // try to calculate the result in parallel.
        const promiseArray = [];
        promiseArray.push(this.anotherService.job2(a));
        promiseArray.push(this.anotherService.job2(a + 1));
        promiseArray.push(this.anotherService.job2(a - 1));

        await Promise.all(promiseArray).then((results: MyObject[]) => {
            for (const obj of results) {
                if (obj.Index === 1) {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

The `anotherService.job2()` has return type `Promise<MyObject>`.

I prepared my test data, set break point to `return obj;` and `return null;`, and it first stopped at `return obj;` then at `return null;`. Therefore the caller of this function gets `null` eventually.

If I change code to

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private readonly anotherService: AnotherService) { }

    public async job1(a: number): Promise<MyObject> {
        // try to calculate the result in parallel.
        const promiseArray = [];
        promiseArray.push(this.anotherService.job2(a));
        promiseArray.push(this.anotherService.job2(a + 1));
        promiseArray.push(this.anotherService.job2(a - 1));

        const results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
        for (const obj of results) {
            if (obj.Index === 1) {
                return obj;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It works.

What is the proper way to use `Promise.all` and return the result from it? When shall I use `Promise.all().then()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Comment: Your second example looks good. What is your problem with it?

Comment: @Evert, no problem. I just try to understand the differences. Am I blocking the thread by using 2nd option if I need to do additional heavy operation in the for loop? I know NodeJs is a single threaded server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the first version of your code is you are only ever returning `null` for the `job1` function.

You could re-write like this, take note that we are returning the result of the then:

```js
...
        return await Promise.all(promiseArray).then((results: MyObject[]) => {
            for (const obj of results) {
                if (obj.Index === 1) {
                    return obj;
                }
            }

            return null;
        });
...
```

To answer your question, of when to use what when. I think that comes down to what of the two approaches you find is simplest, easiest-to-read and maintain.

I personally prefer your second approach.

Comment: Thanks, if I need to add more heavy operations in the for loop, any differences between 2 approaches in terms of thread blocking?