# Why does a object method not return a value?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, return-value

In the following code, the function `findById()` does not actually return anything. The `console.log()`s fire and print as expected but the result is that the variable the function is being called to is undefined.

I have tried to change return value types, even simply putting `return true;` at the end with no conditional, but it always is undefined. To make sure I was not missing something simple I actually created a function that only returns a value `istrue()`. This actually works fine.

This is the object/method def

```
const database = {
    // List of authenticated characters
    characters: [],
    addCharacter: function(c) {
        this.characters.push(c);
    },
    findById: function(id) {
        console.log('Searching for character...');
        this.characters.forEach((c) => {
            if (c.id === id) {
                console.log('Found');
                console.log('cid: ' + c.id);
                console.log('id: ' + id);
                return true; // Never actually returns
            }
        });
    },
    istrue: function() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

and where it is being called

```
const find = database.findById(characterIdToFind);
console.log(typeof find); // always undefined
console.log(find); // always undefined
```

I expect there to be some kind of return value in at least one of the permutations of this function I have tried. There is never any change in the return value of the function, simply `undefined`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - return `undefined`

Comment: @randomSoul the return value of `forEach` is irrelevant here. The fact is, `return true;` returns *from the callback*, not from `findById`. And `findById` has no return value itself. You'd get the same result it using `.map`, or `.some` instead of `.forEach`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` statement inside a nested function return from function.

In this case you could use `some()` instead of `forEach()` because you can't break `forEach`.

```
findById: function(id) {
    console.log('Searching for character...');
    return this.characters.some(c => c.id === id)
}
```

If you want to get the object which matches the given condition that use `find()`

```
findById: function(id) {
    console.log('Searching for character...');
    return this.characters.find(c => c.id === id)
}
```

If you see in above both method we are returning `c.id === id` implicitly in each iteration but it doesn't `return` from outer function.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are trying to return from `forEach` & `forEach` does not return anything