# Recursive function always returns undefined at the end. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

When trying to return the amount of children containing :host found in an object, the function always returns `undefined`.

```
const plugin = stylelint.createPlugin(ruleName, isEnabled => {
  let childrenFound = 0;
  childrenFound = lookForChildren(rule.nodes, childrenFound);
  console.log(childrenFound); // Wrong Value: Always undefined
}


let lookForChildren = function(nodes, childFound) {

  if(childFound > 1) {

    console.log(childFound);

    return childFound;

  }

  nodes.forEach(node => {

    if (node.selector != undefined) {

      const selector = node.selector.replace(":host-context", "");

      if (selector.includes(":host")) {

        childFound++;

        return lookForChildren(node.nodes, childFound);

      } else {

        return lookForChildren(node.nodes, childFound);

      }

    }

  });
// This returns the wrong value so i deleted it
return childFound;
};
```

But it should return the childFound variable which is only return when it is greater than 1.

This function checks if a scss document contains a selector with more than one `:host` selector because the browser compiles it differently than expected.

When `childFound` is greater than one:

Expected: `return childFound // Childfound is 2 or higher`

Actual: `childrenFound` is always undefined.

Comment: the return is `undefined` in the case of `node.selector == undefined`

Comment: `return` statement in `forEach` callback only returns for `forEach`, not the outer function. Maybe you should use `for...of` loop.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal—it's in the parameter list of the anonymous function assigned to *lookForChildren*.

Comment: @JaromandaX But i return childFound which always has a number value when i logged in various places.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Hmm.. I'll try that out now

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Thank you Harun, seems like using forEach in recursions isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `for...to` solved my problem. Thanks to @HarunYilmaz for pointing that out and thanks to everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You should return value inside your function and not outside of or below that function just change position of return statement inside the last curly brace. check below code:

```
const plugin = stylelint.createPlugin(ruleName, isEnabled => {
  let childrenFound = 0;
  childrenFound = lookForChildren(rule.nodes, childrenFound);
  console.log(childrenFound); // Wrong Value: Always undefined
}


let lookForChildren = function(nodes, childFound) {

  if(childFound > 1) {

    console.log(childFound);

    return childFound;

  }

  nodes.forEach(node => {

    if (node.selector != undefined) {

      const selector = node.selector.replace(":host-context", "");

      if (selector.includes(":host")) {

        childFound++;

        return lookForChildren(node.nodes, childFound);

      } else {

        return lookForChildren(node.nodes, childFound);

      }

    }

  });
return childFound;
};

// This returns the wrong value so i deleted it
```

Comment: That was a typo in my code. Sorry about that. The return statement will return a wrong value. For example it should return 2 but returns 1. I'm building a for...to loop now. See if that will work