# Filtering an array of Objects based on a query object

Tags: javascript, filter, foreach

Can't seem to return what I wanting.  Eventually, I want to return an array of objects, or a single object that matches possibly two different partial key/value filters. In other words:
const curQuery = {name:'Nex', tacTechnology: 'Dat'}

I'm planning on having multiple filters in the header of a table.

```
 const data = [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Unified Communications Portal",
            "tacTechnology": "Collaboration"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "ACE Training Portal",
            "tacTechnology": "Networking Services"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Nexus 5K/2K Training Portal",
            "tacTechnology": "Data Center"
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "XR Training Portal",
            "tacTechnology": "Routing"
        }]

const curQuery = {name:'Nex'}

function setFilteredItems(curQuery) {
  const curQueryKeys = Object.keys(curQuery)
  const filteredItems = data.filter(
    (item) => {
      curQueryKeys.forEach((objKey) => {
        if (item[objKey] === undefined || curQuery[objKey] === null){
          console.log('its not', item[objKey], curQuery[objKey])
          return false;
        }
       else if(item[objKey].toLowerCase().includes(curQuery[objKey].toLowerCase())) {
         console.log('it includes', item[objKey], curQuery[objKey])
         return item;
         }
      })
    }
  )
  console.log('filteredItems', filteredItems )
}

setFilteredItems(curQuery);
```

Expecting filteredItems to be {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Nexus 5K/2K Training Portal",
            "tacTechnology": "Data Center"
        }, but getting nothing back.

I created a quick codepen here: https://codepen.io/bmarker/pen/mddEdma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning inside your `forEach` call, which just [exits the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function) (something like `continue`). If you use a conventional `for` loop, your code works as you would expect because then the `return` is for the function you passed for `filter`:

```js
const data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Unified Communications Portal",
  "tacTechnology": "Collaboration"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "ACE Training Portal",
  "tacTechnology": "Networking Services"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Nexus 5K/2K Training Portal",
  "tacTechnology": "Data Center"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "name": "XR Training Portal",
  "tacTechnology": "Routing"
}]

const curQuery = {
  name: 'Nex'
}

function setFilteredItems(curQuery) {
  const curQueryKeys = Object.keys(curQuery)
  const filteredItems = data.filter((item) => {
    for (const objKey of curQueryKeys) {
      if (item[objKey] === undefined || curQuery[objKey] === null) {
        console.log('its not', item[objKey], curQuery[objKey])
        return false;
      } else if (item[objKey].toLowerCase().includes(curQuery[objKey].toLowerCase())) {
        console.log('it includes', item[objKey], curQuery[objKey])
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  console.log('filteredItems', filteredItems)
}

setFilteredItems(curQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the key/values form the query object and iterate the entries by checking the object's value with the wanted value.

If you want not all properties of the query, you could replace [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function getItems(query) {
    var entries = Object.entries(query).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.toLowerCase()]);
    return data.filter(o => entries.every(([k, v]) => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(v)));
}

const
    data = [{ id: "1", name: "Unified Communications Portal", tacTechnology: "Collaboration" }, { id: "2", name: "ACE Training Portal", tacTechnology: "Networking Services" }, { id: "3", name: "Nexus 5K/2K Training Portal", tacTechnology: "Data Center" }, { id: "4", name: "XR Training Portal", tacTechnology: "Routing" }];

console.log(getItems({ name: 'Nex' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```