# Returning result from forEach results in undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a function that loops through a list using `forEach` and I want to return a result early (mimicking `break`). But the function returns undefined. Why does it return undefined?

[Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nedgar8/f3hcup7e/)

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const test = () => {
  const rs = list.forEach(item => {
    return item
  })
   return rs
}
const rs = test()

console.log(rs)
```

Comment: `test` doesn't return anything...

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function

Comment: this post has no sense ... foreach not return a value and in your example is not clear what is what you want to obtain (the same array?)

Answer (score 0):

The function `forEach` does not return a value. You'd be better off using `find`. At this point, it's unclear what you want to do with your loop so I'm assuming that you are trying to return a value based on a condition.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

Also, the way you are calling your function is wrong. You are setting a variable inside a callback but never returning the variable. The `test` function returns nothing. Hence you get undefined.

You should return the value of the `find` function.

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const test = () => {
  return list.find(item => {
      if(/* some condition */ item > 1) {
        return item
      }
  })
}
const rs = test()

console.log(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if there is something in the list you need this - note test needs to return something for the log to show anything

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const test = () => {
  const rs = list.filter(item => {
    return item!=null
  })
  return rs.length>0;
}
const rs = test()

console.log(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, forEach return undefined. see this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

you can use map instead,which returns an array and do not forget to return it in a map

```
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const test = () => {
  const rs = list.map(item => {
      return item
  })
  return rs;
}
const rs = test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix this problem this way.

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const test = () => {
  const rs = [];
list.forEach(item => {
    rs.push(item);
  })
   return rs;
}
const rs = test();

console.log(rs);
```