# Why is console.log() logging undefined when my function seems to be returning the right answer?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to make a basic score tracker using JavaScript:

```
function Player(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.scores = [];
}

function addPlayer(name) {
    playersList.push(new Player(name));
    return playersList;
}

function addScore(name, score) {
    playersList.forEach(player => {
        if (player.name == name) {
            player.scores.push(score);
        };
    });
}

function getTotal(name) {
    playersList.forEach(player => {
        if (player.name == name) {
            let sum = 0;
            player.scores.forEach(score => sum += score);
            console.log(sum);
        } 
    });
}

var playersList = [];
addPlayer("Player1");
addScore("Player1", 3);
addScore("Player1", 4);
console.log(getTotal("Player1"));
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
7
7
```

but instead I get:

```
7
undefined
```

Could anyone help me as to why my `console.log()` does not log the number returned from the function?

Comment: Because the function doesn't actually have a return in it.

Comment: @takendarkk My bad, I changed my `return sum` to the `console.log()` just before I posted. Even with `return sum` it logs `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
function getTotal(name) {
  let sum = 0;
  playersList.forEach(player => {
    if (player.name == name) {        
        player.scores.forEach(score => sum += score);
        console.log(sum);
    } 
  });
  return sum
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works the way I want it to. Could you possibly help me figure out why this works? Is it because the `let` keyword declared `sum` only inside the `if` block?

Comment: I'm not expert at this but you can refer to this link.  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function. 
     
You need to declare variable outside the forEach, then you manipulate that variable inside, if so you can return the total sum in the end of function.  Cuz you cannot return something in forEach, doing so will not break the loop