# Vue, can't get why it acting strange in a function. Runs 5 times forEach when there is a return

Tags: javascript, vue.js

That's my whole test file. I've done so far, validation and it changes `span` class correctly due to correctly or not correctly fulfilled input. But where I'm stuck is I want disable `button` if there is not correctly fulfilled input or empty at all. And I think I've done logic right, but it doesn't work. I consoled.loged it, I see where is an issue, but why it happens for me is a mystery.

In short what happens: button is signed to variable `button`, and inputs on every input event calling function `ft_button` which check's if inputs are correctly fulfilled and buy that result it changes variable `button`. And it would have been fine, but in this function I don't know why it runs forEach cycle 5 times when there is `return` written. Is it some sort of JS thing? Cause in C if there is a return it stopps looping no matter what. And of course it will print out `active` at the end since it just skips all `returns` in forEach loop.[image: pic of console.log]

on pic you can see it logs 5 times `2` which is actually a surprise for me, cause after `return` it should just stop looping. Gmm how then should I return `active` or `disabled`...

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <title>1</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
         <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="js/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="sample">
                    <form>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group" v-for="v in info">
                            <label v-bind:for='v.name'>{{ v.name | capitalize }}</label><span :class="alertType(v.value)"></span>
                            <input id="intra" type="text" class="form-control" v-on:input="checkInput($event, v)">
                            <div>{{ v.value ? 'true' : 'false'}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" :class="button">
                        Send Data
                    </button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        <script>
        Vue.filter('capitalize', function (value) {
              if (!value) return '';
              value = value.toString();
              return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
        })

            new Vue({
                el: '.sample',
                data: {
                    button: 'disabled',
                    info: [
                        {
                            name: 'intra',
                            value: '',
                            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'phone',
                            value: '',
                            pattern: /^[0-9]{7,14}$/
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'email',
                            value: '',
                            pattern: /.+/
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'password',
                            value: '',
                            pattern: /.+/
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'repeatPassword',
                            value: '',
                            pattern: /.+/
                        }
                    ]
                },
                methods:
                {
                    checkInput(e, obj){
                        obj.value = obj.pattern.test(e.target.value);
                        this.button = this.ft_button();
                    },
                    alertType(value)
                    {
                        if(value === true)
                            return "fa fa-check-circle";
                        if(value === false)
                            return "fa fa-exclamation-circle";
                    },
                    ft_button()
                    {
                        this.info.forEach((el) =>
                            {
                                if (el.value === false || el.value === '')
                                {
                                    console.log(2);
                                    return 'disabled';
                                }
                            })
                        console.log(1);
                        return 'active';
                    }
                },
                computed:
                {
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Comment: yes it worked thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't return from `forEach` the same way you can in a vanilla for loop. This question may be helpful: [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Comment: I'll try, but I think it answers it up thanx