# JavaScript check if letter is contain or not in a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript function using which I want to check if the **first** element of the array called `mutation` contains all the letters of the second element.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  let test    = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let target  = arr[0].toLowerCase();

  let split = test.split('');

  split.forEach((elem)=>{
    if(target.indexOf(elem) < 0 ) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return true;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Now it should show me boolean `false` because letter **y** does not exist in **hello** word. but it's doesn't.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot `return` from inside `forEach`. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function

Comment: Oh. I see!!! Thanks for that info.

Comment: Should `mutation(["hello", "helo"])` return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try another approach to get the expected results:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  let test    = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('').join('');
  let target  = arr[0].toLowerCase().split('').join('');
  return target.includes(test);
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Try with `['hello world', 'hello']`. The sorted strings are `[" dehllloorw", "ehllo"]`, where `includes` returns `false`

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let test = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let target = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let split = test.split('');
  return split.every(x => target.includes(x)); // checks if all letters of `split` exists in `target`
}
console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));
console.log(mutation(["hello", "heo"]));
console.log(mutation(["helloworld", "lloword"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let test    = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let target  = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  return target.includes(test);
}

console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));
console.log(mutation(["helloworld", "hello"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Return statement inside the ForEach won't return from the function, you can use a simple for loop or a reduce to get the end result in on line

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let test    = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let target  = arr[0].toLowerCase();

  let split = test.split('');

  const result = split.reduce((acc, curr) => acc && target.includes(curr), true);

  return result;
}

console.log(mutation(['hello', 'y']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick to more classical methods:

```js
console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));

function mutation(args) {
  const target  = args[0].toLowerCase();
  const test    = args[1].toLowerCase();
  
  for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i += 1) {
  
    if (target.indexOf(test[i]) < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    
  }
  return true;
}
```