# Function always returning same value

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a game that enables users to place pieces onto a grid. Once a piece has been placed on the grid, there should be some functionality that prevents further pieces from being added in the same grid positions. Below is what I have designed so far for this feature.

The issue I am having is that the function always returns false, thereby enabling pieces to be continually added into the same grid positions, even if there is a ship placed.
`start` and `end` are both integer values and `direction` is either horizontal or vertical:

```
    const checkIfShipPresent = (direction, start, end) => {
        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                shipYard.forEach((ship => {
                    if (ship.position.includes(i)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }))
            };
            return false;
```

The below code illustrates how I have been attempting to test the function:

```
    const checkIfShipPresent = (direction, start, end) => {
        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                shipYard.forEach((ship => {
                    console.log(ship.position)
                    console.log(i)
                    console.log(ship.position.includes(i))
                    if (ship.position.includes(i)) {
                        console.log("triggered")
                        return true;
                    }
                }))
            };
            console.log("firing")
            return false;
```

Here is the associated console log results (with a ship placed at grid positions [0,1,2,3,4] and clicking on cell 0):

```
gameboardFactory.js:71 (5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
gameboardFactory.js:72 0
gameboardFactory.js:73 true
gameboardFactory.js:75 triggered
gameboardFactory.js:71 (5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
gameboardFactory.js:72 1
gameboardFactory.js:73 true
gameboardFactory.js:75 triggered
gameboardFactory.js:71 (5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
gameboardFactory.js:72 2
gameboardFactory.js:73 true
gameboardFactory.js:75 triggered
gameboardFactory.js:71 (5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
gameboardFactory.js:72 3
gameboardFactory.js:73 true
gameboardFactory.js:75 triggered
gameboardFactory.js:71 (5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
gameboardFactory.js:72 4
gameboardFactory.js:73 true
gameboardFactory.js:75 triggered
gameboardFactory.js:80 firing
```

I need the function to return true if there is a ship present, but as you can see it doesn't ever break out of the loop and consequently will always return false.

Comment: the `return true` is from the function inside the `forEach` (which ignores its return value) - you're not actually returning from the `checkIfShipPresent` function

Comment: Consider using `const foundTarget = shipYard.some(ship => { ... })` -- `return true;` will now break out of the loop and propagate to `foundTarget`, which you can test and return.

Comment: BTW, forEach never stops even if you return.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely again at this section of your code - particularly the `return true;`:

```
for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    shipYard.forEach((ship => {
        if (ship.position.includes(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }))
};
return false;
```

`return` returns from - and exits - the function it's inside. Which here is the anonymous arrow function passed to the `forEach` method. Note that `forEach` actually ignores any return value of the callback passed to it - it's only ever useful for any side effects of the function passed to it.

If you wish to return `true` from your wider function when the `if` condition holds, you should use a standard `for` loop instead of `forEach`. This doesn't involve any functions, so `return` will do as you want:

```
for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    for (const ship of shipYard) {
        if (ship.position.includes(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }))
};
return false;
```

(I've used the more concise `for ... of` loop form, but a regular `for (let j = 0; j < shipYard.length; j++)` style loop would also work fine.)