# I cant look for a value in a object array, it returns me error

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, scope

Hello everyone I'm doing this music player and this is the song loader but the problem is that when I try to assing the value to song constant with `lookSongbyId` function it returns me an error idk why

```
let queue = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Crush',
        artist: 'Glades',
    }
]

const loadSong = (id) =>{


    function lookSongbyId(id)
    {
        queue.forEach(currentSong => {
            if(currentSong.id == id )
            {
                return currentSong
            }   
        })
    }

    const song = lookSongbyId(id)


    console.log(`la canción ${song.name} ha sido cargada`)
}
loadSong(1)
```

`song` constant is undefined, and I dont know why aghhh
If u could help me with this code I've been so thankful with u :DDD

Comment: Syntax: `functionlookSongbyId(id)`. Also, you should load the whole array of `queue` and then run each object of array through `.forEach()`.

Comment: thanks i didnt realize of this typo but it was only when i wrote the question, in my original code it isnt but it doesnt work :c

Comment: Returning from a forEach handler goes to the next iteration, it does not return a value for its outer function. Use a for of loop instead, or one of the suggested answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the `functionlookSongbyId` is just misspelled (you must write `function lookSongbyId`), the `forEach` function cannot be used to return a value, as indirectly said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function).
Use a `for ... of` or `.find()` to retrieve the element

Answer (score 3):

you can use directly filter if you want to return more than item or find if you want only want (if the id is unique)

```
const queue = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Crush',
        artist: 'Glades',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Another Song2',
        artist: 'Favio Figueroa',
      }
    ];
    const useFilter = queue.filter((row) => row.id === 1 );
    console.log('useFilter', useFilter) // [ { id: 1, name: 'Crush', artist: 'Glades' } ]
    const useFind = queue.find((row) => row.id === 2 );
    console.log('useFind', useFind) // { id: 2, name: 'Another Song2', artist: 'Favio Figueroa' }
```

you can add in your function that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your function to just use `find` which will return the matched song.

```
let queue = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Crush',
        artist: 'Glades',
    }
]

const loadSong = (id) =>{
    const song = queue.find(x => x.id === id)
    console.log(`la canción ${song.name} ha sido cargada`)
    return song
}
loadSong(1)
```

Comment: Woow thaanks it really helps me a lot

Answer (score -1):

Don't create a function for the song search, you can use find and get the right song seamlessly:

```
const loadSong = (id) => {
    const song = queue.find( sng => sng.id === id);
    console.log(`la canción ${song.name} ha sido cargada`)
}
```

Comment: Interesting method! thanks for your help