# forEach and map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just tried tried solving a task on codewars.
The question is to write a function that reverse every word in a string that is greater than or equal to 5.

When I tried using forEach it doesn't change the element until I used map.

And according to MDN page,

> forEach() does not mutate the array on which it is called. (However, callbackFn may do so)

So am expecting the array to mutate since I passed a callbackfn to it.

```
function spinWords(string){
 let a = string.split(" ");
//   console.log(a);
  a.forEach(el => {
    if (el.length >= 5) {
      let reverseSting = el.split("").reverse().join("");
      console.log(reverseSting);
      return reverseSting;
    }
    else {
//       
      return el;
    }
  })
  console.log(a);
  return a.join(" ");
}
```

```
function spinWords(string){
 let a = string.split(" ");
//   console.log(a);
  a = a.map(el => {
    if (el.length >= 5) {
      let reverseSting = el.split("").reverse().join("");
      console.log(reverseSting);
      return reverseSting;
    }
    else {
//       
      return el;
    }
  })
  console.log(a);
  return a.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: "*so am expecting the the array to mutate since i passed a callbackfn to it.*" why would you expect that? The callback functiopn doesn't cause any mutation. Nor does [a `return` in a `forEach` do anything at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function) related to the array.

Comment: When it is suggested that a callback can mutate the array, it means nothing else than that the callback would explicitly assign a new value to an array entry. Returning a value has no meaning in a `forEach` callback.

Comment: @VLAZ So i can't mutate an array with a forEach

Comment: @lawalolawale not with a callback function that doesn't result in any mutation, no.

Comment: @VLAZ but i can use return in map to modify the element and store it in a new array right?

Comment: `return` doesn't *modify* anything. Mapping is the act of transforming one array to another in 1:1 relation described via a mapping function. The result of the function is an entry in the new array. Ideally, the mapping function doesn't mutate anything.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks you very much..i really appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither function, `map` or `forEach` mutate the original array. The difference here is that `map` returns a new array while `forEach` doesn't. Which is why you have

```
a = a.map(el => {
```

You assign the array returned by the `map` back to the variable `a`. With a `forEach` the return values inside the callback are not used and there is no new array to work with.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const square = number => number * number
// logs [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
console.log(array.map(square))
// logs undefined
console.log(array.forEach(square))
```

Comment: To further demonstrate JaKub's point, please look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8cSC.png

For more info, take a look at the [forEach documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: I do not want to use the word never, because `arrayOfObjects.forEach(obj => { delete obj.prop })` kind of breaks the idea of "never", so the callback can mutate in a way.

Comment: @JakubMichálek Thanks alot.I really appreciate