# document.createElement variable return from a function as undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, undefined, return-value, appendchild, createelement

I have this code:

```js
/* Creating whole HTML Units from HTML Element list */
function createHTMLUnit(unitstruct){
  var tempElement;
  Object.entries(unitstruct).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // First of all we start a loop
    if(typeof value==='object'&&key==='$child'){ //Find out that we have an Object and it's a child
      //If yes we append this as a child to the tempElement with call this function again
      tempElement.appendChild(createHTMLUnit(value));
    }else{
      //If not we reach a single element have to find out what we should do with it
      //Switch from the cases like '$tag', '$attr', '$child' or other (will be a value)
      switch(key){
        case '$tag': //Createing the element in value
            tempElement = document.createElement(value);
          break;
        case '$attr': //Loop through the value and set attributes for the element
            Object.entries(value).forEach(([attrkey, attrvalue]) => {
              tempElement.setAttribute(attrkey, attrvalue);
            })
          break;
        case '$child': //Element innerHTML
            return tempElement;
          break;
        default:  //Return with the value to the previous loop
            return tempElement;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
  
  var htmlUnitParam = {
      '$tag': 'div',
      '$attr': {
        'class':'msg-box',
        'id':'msg-box01'
      },
      '$child': {
        '$tag': 'div',
        '$attr': {
          'class':'msg-box-container',
          'id':'msg-box-container01'
        },
        '$child': ''
      }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(createHTMLUnit(htmlUnitParam));
```

If I run this it will be drop an "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." error. If I take things apart like:

```js
var x = createHTMLUnit(value);
tempElement.appendChild(x);
```

'x' gonna be undefined after createHTMLUnit returns (as I checked in Chrome Inspector, at the point'return tempElement;' tempElement hold it's value and the function return undefined...) so appendChild can't apply anything to the node.

Anybody have any idea what is the problem? And how can I fix it?
(And yes, I should use recrusion and a function like this one...)

Comment: Not all paths are returning something, that's why. Some paths return `undefined`

Comment: `createHTMLUnit` doesn't return anything at all. Take a closer look at your code and consider which function actually contains your `return` statements. Answer: it's the callback function that you pass to the `forEach` method, NOT `createHTLUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a value from the function, but your return statements are inside a forEach loop callback function. Returning inside the loop doesn't return from the outer function, so at the end of the loop it just returns nothing.

[Related info on forEach return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

That link contains some other alternatives, but basically you want to replace the forEach loop with a regular for loop, going through the Object.keys or Object.values and then your returns should start to function as you originally expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody!

Meanwhile I just find an other way (maybe it's a bit comfortable as well) to get it to work.

```js
function createHTMLUnit(unitstruct, appendto){
  var tempElement;
  Object.entries(unitstruct).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if(typeof value==='object'&&key==='$child'){
      createHTMLUnit(value, tempElement);
    }else{
      switch(key){
        case '$tag':
            tempElement = document.createElement(value);
          break;
        case '$attr':
            Object.entries(value).forEach(([attrkey, attrvalue]) => {
              tempElement.setAttribute(attrkey, attrvalue);
            })
          break;
        case '$child':
            tempElement.innerHTML = value;
            return;
          break;
        default:
            createHTMLUnit(value, appendto);
          break;
      }
    }
  });
  if(tempElement!=undefined){ 
    appendto.appendChild(tempElement);
  }
}
```

Maybe it's not that nice but it works fine.