# Return dataset that contains class javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a color buttons which the user can select only one color. If the button is click, the button that was clicked will have class 'color__active'. I'm trying to get the `<button>` with a `dataset['color']` that contains CSS class 'color__active`but it returns`undefined`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
  <button
    class="product__color color__active flex h-5 w-5 items-center justify-center rounded-full text-white"
    style="background-color: #000"
    data-color="#000"
  >
    <svg class="h-4 w-4 fill-current">
      <use xlink:href="http://localhost:1234/icons.fc114240.svg?1649745862008#icon-check"></use>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button
    class="product__color  flex h-5 w-5 items-center justify-center rounded-full text-white"
    style="background-color: #ff0000"
    data-color="#ff0000"
  ></button>
</div>;
```

**JavaScript**

```
let color = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.product__color')).forEach(c => {
  return c.classList.contains('color__active') && c.dataset.color;
});
```

Comment: You can't use `return` inside a `.forEach` method. (And _no-one_ should be using `.forEach` today anyway)

Comment: What should happen if multiple buttons have the CSS class `product__color` applied?

Comment: [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653612)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`Array.prototype.forEach` does not do what you think it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

  - It invokes the inner function for every element in the array.
  - Crucially (in your case), **it does not support returning values**, nor finding elements in an array.
- Also, in general: don't use `Array.prototype.forEach`.

  - It isn't intended to be used as a *pure* function (unlike `Array.protoype.map` or `Array.prototype.filter`) which makes it harder to reason about (e.g. what happens if you modify the array while inside the `forEach` callback?).
  - Also, [it's impossible to control iteration inside the body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20way%20to%20stop%20or%20break), and careless use of it often inadvertently captures state in its closure which is a frequent source of bugs.

    - `Array.prototype.forEach` exists only because earlier versions of JavaScript didn't have a simple way to iterate through general collection-types.
  - Instead, [use the modern `for( of )` statement instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

    - Which is also [*much* faster too](https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead).
- Also, your logic in your `.forEach` inner func can be moved to the selector:

  - `c.classList.contains('color__active')` is the same as using `.color__active` in the selector.
  - The check for a non-falsy (i.e. non-empty) `c.dataset.color` can be added to the CSS selector by using the "has non-empty attribute" selector: `[data-color]:not([data-color=""i])`

    - Surprisingly CSS doesn't have an "attribute-value not-equal-to X" selector, but you can use `:not([attribute-name="value"])` as a logically-equivalent, if more verbose, alternative.
  - And you should add the `button` element type to the selector too:
  - So the final selector is: `button.product__color.color__active[data-color]:not([data-color=""i])`
- Then just use `document.querySelector` to grab the *first element* (rather than *all elements*) that match the selector instead of using `querySelectorAll`.

  - Though it would be a good idea to check if there are multiple elements matching the selector and then `throw new Error()`, just to be safe.

---

So change your code to just this:

```js
const firstColorButtonOrNull = document.querySelector( 'button.product__color.color__active[data-color]:not([data-color=""i])' ) ?? null;
const color = firstColorButtonOrNull?.dataset['color'] ?? null;
```

- The `?? null` at the end of each line [is to coalesce `undefined` to `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) which is often easier to process in JS.
- The `?.` [is the *safe chaining* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (also known as the *Elvis operator* or the *safe navigation* operator in other languages).

  - So *if* `firstColorButtonOrNull` is `null` or `undefined`, then the expression evaluates to `undefined` instead of crashing.

    - The second `?? null` at the end is so that `color` will be `null` instead of `undefined`.

...which can then be simplified down to a single-liner:

```js
const firstColorOrNull = document.querySelector( 'button.product__color.color__active[data-color]:not([data-color=""i])' )?.dataset['color'] ?? null;
```

---

#### Consider using defensive programming practices:

This alternative implementation below (`getFirstActiveColorOrNull`) ensures there's only ever 0 or 1 elements with `.product__color` otherwise it throws an error. This approach [is an example of *defensive programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), and should be used if you care about correctness and self-documenting code (as it *demonstrates intent*: as with your current code it's unclear to anyone else *if* `product__color` is only meant to be used at-most once or not).

```js
function getFirstActiveColorOrNull() {

  const selector = 'button.product__color.color__active[data-color]:not([data-color=""i])';

  function getFirstOrNull( elements, projection ) {
    if( colorButtons.length == 0 ) {
      return null;
    }
    else if( colorButtons.length == 1 ) {
      return projection( colorButtons[0] );
    }
    else { // Implicit: colorButtons.length > 1
      throw new Error( "Encountered multiple elements matching selector \"" + selector + "\". This should never happen." );
    }
  }
  
  const colorButtons = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
  return getFirstOrNull( colorButtons, el => el.dataset.color );
}

//

function makeMeActive( button ) {
    
    const otherActiveElements = document.querySelectorAll( '.color__active' );
    for( const el of otherActiveElements ) el.classList.remove( 'color__active' );
    
    button.classList.add( 'color__active' );
}
```

```css
.color__active {
    outline: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
  <button
    class="product__color color__active flex h-5 w-5 items-center justify-center rounded-full text-white"
    style="background-color: #000; color: white;"
    data-color="#000"
    onclick="makeMeActive(this)"
  >
   Black
  </button>

  <button
    class="product__color  flex h-5 w-5 items-center justify-center rounded-full text-white"
    style="background-color: #ff0000"
    data-color="#ff0000"
    onclick="makeMeActive(this)"
  >Red</button>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Click a button to make it "active": it will be given a blue border.</p>

<button onclick="console.log( getFirstActiveColorOrNull() )">Click me to print active color to console</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What does 'i' do in this line [data-color=""i]?

Comment: [The `i` means _case-insensitive_ match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It's not necessary when comparing to an empty attribute value `=""` but I always use it just-in-case I change it to a non-empty value. You can use `s` for a case-sensitive match (the default is case-sensitive). Also, the `i` and `s` options only apply to ASCII-range characters (i.e. `A-Za-z`).

Comment: Should I use for of loop instead of forEach?

Comment: @J.Wujeck You don't need _any_ loops if you're only interested in a single element. Please read my answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the color using this querySelector:

```js
let color = document.querySelector(".product__color.color__active")?.dataset
  ?.color;
```