# typescript what to return in this function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have a function `whoWins()` which is supposed to return based on some `if` conditions. I'm receiving the return in another function `controller` in this case, i'm getting an error in typescript saying that my `whoWins()` function is `void`, which i'm assuming it's because it's not really returning anything outside of the `if` conditions.

i'm wondering what's the correct way to handle this situation:

```
  whoWins(
    player1Choice: string,
    player2Choice: string
  ): { player1Score: number; player2Score: number; message: string } // error here: A // function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. 
{
   ruleSet.forEach((rule: IRuleSet, index: number) => {
      if (player1Choice == ruleSet[index].choice) {
        if (rule.losesTo.includes(player2Choice)) {
          console.log('player2Score', this._player2Score);
          return {
            player1Score: this._player1Score,
            player2Score: ++this._player2Score,
            message: 'player2 Wins',
          };
        } else if (rule.beats.includes(player2Choice)) {
          return {
            player1Score: ++this._player1Score,
            player2Score: this._player2Score,
            message: 'player1 Wins',
          };
        } else {
          return {
            player1Score: this._player1Score,
            player2Score: this._player2Score,
            message: 'Draw',
          };
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```
  public play(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { player1Move, player2Move } = req.body;
    const game = new Game();
    const { player1Score, player2Score } = game.whoWins(
      player1Move,
      player2Move
    );
    res.render('game', { data: req.body, player1Score: 1, player2Score: 0 });
  }
```

Comment: Well all your function does is to initialise `const payload`. It doesn't actually `return` anything.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653612/1048572). But even if that was no problem, your function wouldn't return anything if the `ruleSet` was empty.

Comment: my bad, `const payload` wasn't supposed to be there, edit added.