# React Native - For Loop components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to for loop numbers of components, but it seem didn't work. I `setState` the `totalitem` to 5, and the output components only have 1.

```
_renderSomeItems(){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.state.totalitem; i++){
    return(
      <SpecialItem key={i} />
    );
  }      
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` inside a `for` loop will end the loop. You should use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Don't forget to `return` result of `map`.

```
_renderSomeItems(){
  // considering this.state.totalitem is to be an array
  return this.state.totalitem.map((item, index) => {
    return(
      <SpecialItem key={index} />
    );
  }      
}

// or

_renderSomeItems(){
  const results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.state.totalitem; i++){
    results.push(<SpecialItem key={i} />);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, `this.state.totalitem` is just a number. I mentioned in my question that i `setState` it to `5`

Comment: Then second version is a better option for you. That is why I added the comment on first one

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash

```
import _ from 'lodash'

_renderSomeItems(){
  return _.range(this.state.totalitem).map(item, index) => (
    <SpecialItem key={i} />
  );
}
```