# For Loop in react-native render only index[0]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-native

I don't understand why my loop render me only index[0] in my loop....
I have à state that's an array :

```
this.state = {
      days: ["Lundi","Mardi","Mercredi"]
    }
```

And i want to render each day in my component:

```
render(){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.days.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.days[i]);
      return (

        <Text>{this.state.days[i]}</Text>

      );
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: Hint, what does the `return` statement do?

Comment: Because of return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are returning within your for loop which [breaks the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop)

You are best to use map

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { 
          array.map(day => {
            return (
              <p>{day}</p>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You break the loop with the `return` command, so it's enter only once to the loop

Answer (score 0):

Your render method should be like this:

```
render(){
    return(
       <View>
         {this.state.days.map((item, index) => {
             <Text>{item}</Text>
           }
         )}
       </View>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.render` must return a single root node. This way you're returning multiple nodes.

You need to do something like (wrap your content in a div)

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.days.map(d => <Text>{d}</Text>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 render() {
        this.state = {
            days: ["jan","feb","Mar"]
          } 
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              { 
              this.state.days.map(d => <Text>{d}</Text>)
            }
            </View>
        )
 }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!