# Why i only get one value after executing "for loop" to display "datasets.data" in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have successfully displayed the value, but why is only one value displayed? I want the value in sequence

**This my code**

```
/*my datasets code*/
datasets: [{
  label: 'Daily Data',
  data: [730000, 1012000, 1220000, 1831000, 560000, 2012000, 890000],
  borderColor: '#3f89fb',
  borderWidth: 3,
  fill: false
}]

/*my tooltips code*/
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chart.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
        return chart.datasets[0].data[i] / 1e6 + 'M';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**and this my result, all day value is 0.73M**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the [Tooltip Item](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface) Documentation.

In your case tooltipItem.index contains the index of this data item in the dataset. So you can return the value doing so:

```
function(tooltipItem, chart) {
    return chart.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index] / 1e6 + 'M';
}
```

And here is the demo:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Daily Data',
            data: [730000, 1012000, 1220000, 1831000, 560000, 2012000, 890000],
            borderColor: '#3f89fb',
            borderWidth: 3,
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
                    return chart.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index] / 1e6 + 'M';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: so great, sorry I didn't read the documentation in detail, btw thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

This is because return stops execution and exits the function. return always exits its function immediately, with no further execution if it's inside a loop.

See this answer:
[Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return inside for loop which will exit the loop, you can save your results somewhere like below

```
var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < chart.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
        result.push(chart.datasets[0].data[i] / 1e6 + 'M');
      }
```