# How to loop inside return statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

In react native in jsx i want a function to return a loop like these, I am doing like this but my code is saying unreachable in this case.

```
<View>
  {()=>{
   return ( for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
               <Text>Hello World</Text>
          })
   }}
</View>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display, `Hello World` 5x?

Comment: @bertdida yes i want  to display 5 times

Comment: check out this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop

Answer (score 2):

You can only render a React element.

Here is a simple example, although `for` loops are barely used.

```
let content = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  content.push(<h1>Hello World using for loop</h1>);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {content}
      {[...Array(5).keys()].map((key) => (
        <h1 key={key}>Hello World using map</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I need for for loop because I need to use the property for-in  in my condition also  like for(var i in array){}

Answer (score 0):

use map instead of loop.

```
Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((v) => <Text key={v}>{v}</Text>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions:

1. Writing 5x Hello world

// Function

```
getList(){
    let texts = []
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        texts.push(<Text>Hello World</Text>)
    }
    return texts
}
```

// Render

```
<View>
    {this.getList()}
</View>
```

2. Mapping an array of values

// Array

```
const list = [
    "Hello World",
    "Ad adipisicing ea ut in officia.",
    "Consectetur ipsum commodo reprehenderit sit est aliquip commodo ad qui duis et exercitation.",
    "Est sint esse veniam laborum cillum ullamco aliquip aute eiusmod cupidatat."
]
```

// Render

```
<View>
    {list.map((text, index) => <Text key={index}>{text}</Text>)}
</View>
```