# for loop not working in typescript javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop

I have an array of objects that contain time from and to
like this

```
[{from:2.3,to:4.5},{from:4.5,to:6}]
```

Now I am trying to loop over this to check my from value the problem here it only get the first item I have tried this with just JavaScript it worked fine but when I used typescript it didn't work as expected it just keep returning the first element on my array and stop
so what might be the problem

```
const freeSchedule = await ConsultFreeTime.findOne({consultantId:"123"})
            .then(schedule=>{
               
                schedule.week[day].sort((a:any,b:any ) => a.from - b.from);
                let week = schedule.week;
                if (week[day]) {
                    let timesRange = week[day];                       
                    let checkData = [];

                    // get number of sessions
                    let sessionsNumber = range / 15 - 1;
                    let back=0;
                    
                 // the problem is on that loop
                   for (let i = 0; i < timesRange.length; i++){
                       if (timesRange[i].from === startTime.from){
                            startTime = timesRange[i];
                            back = i;
                           
                        if (startTime.busy.includes(date) && appointmentCheck) {
                            return {
                                success: false,
                                error: " يوجد موعد في هذا الوقت "
                            }
                        }
                        console.log('11111',timesRange[i + sessionsNumber + 1])
                        if (timesRange[i+ sessionsNumber + 1]) {
                            // this will hold the rest time after patient duration end
                            let newUpdate = timesRange[i + sessionsNumber + 1];
                            // send the total time to the admin panal
                            updatedTime = {
                              from: startTime.from,
                              to: newUpdate.to,
                            };
                          console.log('updatedTime',updatedTime)

                            rangeHolder.push({from:newUpdate.from,to:newUpdate.to})
                            newUpdate.busy.push(date);
                            checkData.push(newUpdate.from);
                          }
                          break;

                       }else {
                            return  {
                                success: false,
                                error: "هذا الوقت غير موجود "
                            }
                            }
                   }
                   while (sessionsNumber > 0) {
                    if (!checkData.includes(startTime.from)) {
                        startTime.busy.push(date);
                        checkData.push(startTime.from);
                        rangeHolder.push({from:startTime.from,to:startTime.to})
                      }
                      back += 1;
                      if (!timesRange[back]) {
                        return  {
                            success: false,
                            error: "خطأ في تحديد مدة الجلسة  "
                        }
                      }
                      if (timesRange[back].busy.includes(date) && appointmentCheck) {
                        return  {
                            success: false,
                            error: "يوجد حجز في هذا الوقت  "
                        }
                      }
                      if (!checkData.includes(timesRange[back].from)) {
                        let restDate = timesRange[back];
                        restDate.busy.push(date);
                        checkData.push(restDate.from);
                        rangeHolder.push({from:restDate.from,to:restDate.to})
                      }
                      sessionsNumber--;
                   }
                }
                console.log('schedule.week',schedule.week)
                return schedule.week;

            }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What does "didn't work as expected" mean? What happened instead?

Comment: it keep stopping after getting the first element on the array

Comment: so it stop at [0] element

Comment: Stops in what way? Throws an error?

Comment: no just stop the looping I have tried to use different value and it keep stopping after the first element I have the same logic in just JavaScript and it work fine

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`return` will always stop the execution of a loop. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714515/4716214
Maybe you want to use `forEach` instead.