# Loop in HTML Collections doesnt loop correctly

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

im trying to loop through my HTML Collections as

```
const nodeItems = document.getElementsByClassName('image-inside')
```

I tried to loop like

```
for(let node of nodeItems) {
     console.log('im node ', node)                
     console.log('im node url' , node.src)
     return writer.createAttributeElement( 'img', {
            src: node.src,
            style: `width:${node.style.width};
                    height:${node.style.height};`,
                    class: 'image-inside'
     } , { priority: 7 } )
}
```

but only the first node were logged TWICE not the second one.
[image]
Any thoughts guys? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks for reading

UPDATE: So i have tried to convert to array. which is okay the logging is good. But the prototype of it is Array, what i should return is Nn ( due to writer.createAttributeElement() ). I dont even think i can achieve this
[image: temp[0]]
[image: The array]

UPDATE2: So currently the array is loaded correctly now
[image]
But when get the data from CKEditor5 through editor.getData()
its still taking the last element
[image]

Still thank you guys so much for reading

Comment: `return` returns from your function, the loop ends there.

Comment: I'd think it would break the code since a return statement isn't valid in a for...of statement.

Comment: Try removing the `return` inside the loop, allowing all items to be targeted

Comment: @KitangaNday it's perfectly valid code, you can return from inside a loop.

Comment: Press F12 and give it a try. You'll get a syntax error. It isn't a loop it's a for..of loop , this should be breaking

Comment: @tevemadar then how can i return all value inside the loop, if the loop is breaking why is it logging twice hm?

Comment: I cant do array and push element, same for the HTML Collections

Comment: You can convert the `nodeItems` list to an array using `Array.from` and then use `map`  instead of `for..of` loop.

Comment: I can post an answer to show you btw

Comment: @KitangaNday `console.log((function(){for(let i of [1,2,3])return i;})());`. Also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Closing_iterators : *In `for...of` loops, abrupt iteration termination can be caused by `break`, `throw` or `return`.*. You had a syntax error, but that wasn't the `return`.

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010: you could describe what you are trying to do, because it's likely doable, but not necessarily this way.

Comment: @tevemadar the reason that `return` is working is because it's in a function. Run it without being wrapped in a function and it fails. The for..of loop isn't returning, the function is.

Comment: @KitangaNday give it up, perhaps. It was obvious that this code is in a function.

Comment: i have provided some more picture in update. Thank you guys for answering me.

Comment: @tevemadar no, not really. Haven't touched react/vue code in a while. But yea, good to learn this.

Comment: @KitangaNday the question was not "why this is syntax error", but "why it runs only once". That's how it's obvious that the `return` was not in top-level code.

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010 what exactly are you trying to achieve, is it that you want whatever the writer creates to be stored somewhere, or do you just want to use the writer (as in, don't store anything). If that is true, then remove `map` and put `forEach`.

Comment: @tevemadar I know that much I read the question, my question was how was this running, never knew a return statement could be used inside of a for..of/in loop and it returns the function itself. It's like having a return inside of a switch statement and that returns for the function that holds it. Doesn't make any sense. Now I'm curious if that would work as well XD

Comment: I have tried forEach but still doesnt work. `writer` is an engine of CKEditor5, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_writer-Writer.html

Comment: Yea, i just saw your update to the question, it shouldn't work. You want the type to be the same as prototype. Just out of curiosity, why do you want the type to be Nn?

Comment: @KitangaNday array methods like `find()`, `some()`, `every()` could all be implemented via returning an item/true/false in the middle of an iteration. Returning from inside a `switch` is perfectly viable too, for example if you write a function for encoding control characters to `\t`, `\n`, `\r` and the like, you could write `switch(c){case '\t':return '\\t';case '\n':return '\\n';case '\r':return '\\r';}return c;`

Comment: @tevemadar I know that about the Array's methods but for..of returning a value for an array, I never thought that would work. I thought only if..else statements were given that privilege. Yea I already tested to check if you can do the same with switch, which is funny cause I tested this and it never worked (obviously because it wasn't in a function). But yea I know now, more tools for the arsenal.

Comment: @tevemadar issue now is that the OP now wants to extend this api's Element class without using any of the prescribed methods. So now I'm thinking of rewriting the code for him so that he uses Element, but then that's kind of what the methods like `createAttributeElement` are designed for. So I don't know really how to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

You are breaking loop with `return` stmt.

See another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714515/1205171

Comment: Then why the first node logging twice?

Comment: You have two elements? But I think it’s different topic. You need to provide you HTML code at least :)

Comment: I don’t know what your `writer` does, but be aware that HTMLCollection is live and mutable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the writer is from an engine in ckeditor5
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_writer-Writer.html

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010 it may run twice perhaps because you are invoking the function itself again?

Comment: I have no clue how to run it twice in these low level code
` conversion.for('dataDowncast').elementToElement( {
            model: 'contentImage',
            view: renderDowncastElement()
        } )`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Use EmptyElement since this is what you end up creating if you extend Element class**

As mentioned in the comments you should remove the `return` statement.

Maybe convert it to an array first and remap the array like so:

```js
let nodeItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image-inside'));

nodeItems = nodeItems.map(function(node) {
     console.log('im node ', node)                
     console.log('im node url' , node.src)
     // Instead of creating your own element from Element (i.e. Nn), why not use Empty Element class instead. It will be what you create anyways I'm guessing
     return writer.createEmptyElement( 'img', {
            src: node.src,
            style: `width:${node.style.width};
                    height:${node.style.height};`,
                    class: 'image-inside'
     } , { priority: 7 } )
});
```

Comment: Ive tried like you and still didnt achieve what i want due to the writer. Thank you

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010 since you are getting images why not use `createEmptyElement` since it's used for elements that don't have children (e.g. img elements). Check my answer.

Comment: Hm, the array is loading correctly but when its come to get the data from the editor its still loading only the last element. Check my update, i have capped some more picture. Thank you sir

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010 I'm getting confused each time you update the question , but it's fine, have you figured it out? What exactly are you trying to get to. That picture shows two image elements, so what do you mean by it's not taking the second one, do you mean it's not getting into the writer instance

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010 OK, I see, it's still only showing the the first image, is it possible if you can share your updated code again?

Comment: I have solved the problem, its due to my lack of knowledge about conversion between model and view of CKEditor. I can show you the link of github to my custom build, u want it?

Comment: @mrpuzzy2010 thanks man, but no. I'm just happy that you resolved it.