# JS search values in the array using loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

how to search the value in te array using loops.. not able to sort out the value what's wrong in this solutions ...

```js
function arrayCheck(arr, value) {
  var arr = [35, 56, 78, 90, 54];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // var value = arr.length;

    if (arr[i] === value) {
      return i;
    } else {
      return "Not found";
    }
  }
}

// // arraycheck(value);
console.log(arrayCheck(56));
```

Comment: `return` will quit your function, so your for loop will stop running and "Not found" will be returned as soon as any item does not equal the input `value`

Comment: There are about a dozen duplicates for this...off to find one. *(Edit: Meh, I need to get back to work and people insist on posting duplicate answers anyway.)*

Comment: Move the `return "not found"` below the `for` loop (and you really shouldn't mix the type of the return value. Always return a number, a boolean, a string, ... but not one or the other)

Comment: Not a real dupelicate, but... [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects 2 arguments - `arr` and `value`. You pass the value (56) in place of the `arr`.

In addition, returning in the `else` means that if the 1st item is not the requested value, the iteration would stop, and return "Not Found".

Pass the array to the function, and return "Not Found" after the loop ends:

```js
function arrayCheck(arr, value) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  
  return "Not found";
}

var arr = [35, 56, 78, 90, 54];

console.log(arrayCheck(arr, 56));
```

A simpler solution would be to use `Array.indexOf()`:

```js
const arrayCheck = (arr, value) => {
  const idx = arr.indexOf(value);
  
  return idx === -1 ? "Not found" : idx;
};

const arr = [35, 56, 78, 90, 54];

console.log(arrayCheck(arr, 56));
```