# javascript function to determine if an array contains a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm getting 'false' for the first test and 'true' for the second test. I'm suppose to create a function that will evaluate to these values. I thought I executed my code in the function correctly but I'm not getting what I'm suppose to be getting. I don't understand what I could be doing wrong here. Any help will be so appreciated. Thanks.

```
// - Given the arrayOfNames, determine if the array contains the given name.
// - If the array contains the name, return true.  If it does not, return false.
// - Hint: Use a loop to "iterate" through the array, checking if each name matches the name parameter.
// 
// Write your code here 

function contains(arrayOfNames, name) {
  for (index = 0; index < arrayOfNames.length; index++) {
    if (arrayOfNames[index] === name) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}

//  -------TESTS---------------------------------------------------------------
//  Run these commands to make sure you did it right. They should all be true.
console.log("-----Tests for Exercise Five-----");
console.log("* Returns true when the array contains the name.");
console.log(contains(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"], "nancy") === true);
console.log("* Returns false when the name is not in the array");
console.log(contains(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"], "fred") === false);
```

Comment: See: [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714503)

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` only if the array doesn't contain the `name`.

What you're trying to do is it will return `true` if the `match` found but it will return `false` as soon as the match not found `arrayOfNames[index] === name)`.

In you first example: Let say `i=0` and the first element is `bob`. So the `arrayOfNames[index]` is `bob` and the `name` you want to search is `nancy`. So when it matches them it is not equal so it will return `false`.

```js
function contains(arrayOfNames, name) {
  for (let index = 0; index < arrayOfNames.length; index++) {
    if (arrayOfNames[index] === name) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

//  -------TESTS---------------------------------------------------------------
//  Run these commands to make sure you did it right. They should all be true.
console.log("-----Tests for Exercise Five-----");
console.log("* Returns true when the array contains the name.");
console.log(
  contains(
    ["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"],
    "nancy"
  ) === true
);
console.log("* Returns false when the name is not in the array");
console.log(
  contains(
    ["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"],
    "fred"
  ) === false
);
```