# Why is my if statement not working javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've created an If statement to return a boolean if a word has to of the same consecutive letters, but my code is only returning false and idk why

```
const doubleLetters = word => {
   let letters = word.split('')

   for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
      if (letters[i] === letters[i + 1]){
         return true
      } else{
         return false
      }
   }
}
```

could someone assist me? I've compared my code to

```
function doubleLetters (word) {
   const letters = word.split('') 
   for (let index = 0; index < letters.length; index++) {
     
     if (letters[index] === letters[index + 1]) {
       return true
     }
   }
   return false
 }
```

which appears to be working correctly. It looks like my code, but maybe I'm missing something since mine is broken.
Thanks in advance

Comment: _"It looks like my code"_ - Not quite. Your code `return`s in the `if` and `else` branch of the loop. And `return` stops the execution of the function it is in - and therefor your loop with the first letter. The working version only returns `true` in the `if` branch. The `false` case is after the loop at the end of the function.

Comment: at the end `index + 1` is out of range

Comment: Possible dupe: [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Andreas's comment is right, this not the same code, there is no `else { return false }` in the original version, this `return false` is out of the loop.

Actualy your loop stop after the first step, or doesn't return anything if the input argument `(word)` is empty

there is also a small error about

```js
if (letters[index] === letters[index + 1]) {
```

> at the end of the string `index +1` is out of range

a correct code should be:

```js
const doubleLetters = word =>
  {
  const letters = word.split('') 
  for (let index = 1; index < letters.length; index++)
    { 
    if (letters[index] === letters[index - 1])
      {
      return true
      }
    }
  return false
  }
  
console.log( doubleLetters('abxxef'))
console.log( doubleLetters('abcdef'))
```

> or, if you want a complete ES6 coding, change your loop type,
> and keep a previous letter before:

```js
const doubleLetters = word =>
  {
  let previous = null
  
  for (let letter of word)
    {
    if (previous === letter) return true
    previous = letter
    }
  return false
  }
  
console.log( doubleLetters('abxxef'))
console.log( doubleLetters('abcdef'))
```

> Or even shorter, with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [and other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

```
const doubleLetters = w => [...w].some((l,i,{[i+1]:n})=>l===n)
```

```js
const doubleLetters = word => [...word].some((letter,i,{[i+1]:next})=>letter===next)  

console.log( doubleLetters('abxxef'))
console.log( doubleLetters('abcdef'))
```

> for info, if you absolutely want to test each letter of the word and their next, you will have to use a flag to summarize the answers

```js
const doubleLetters = word =>
  {
  let
    test = false
  , letters = word.split('')
    ;
  for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) 
    {
    test ||= (letters[i] === letters[i + 1])
    }
  return test
  }

console.log( doubleLetters('abxxef'))
console.log( doubleLetters('abcdef'))
```

Comment: If you use a snippet then please also use the _"Tidy"_ feature (unless the unusual scheme is really as intentional as it is).

Comment: @Andreas It is intentional, I only use the Whitesmiths style. In my opinion the K&R style is not advisable, especially for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else part in your code. Your code will return true only if first 2 character s are same, otherwise else part will be executed and false will be returned.

In the other function code return false is outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the `return false` placement. Let's first walk through the working code and check what it does:

> ```
>  for (let index = 0; index < letters.length; index++) {     
>    if (letters[index] === letters[index + 1]) {
>      return true
>    }
>  }
>  return false
> ```

The above code checks if a letter is the same as a consecutive letter. If it is equal, `true` is returned. If it is not equal we'll move on to the next letter. If all letters are checked and no match has been found then `return false`.

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "b", "c"];
// executes as
"a" === "b" // not equal, next!
"b" === "b" // equal, return true

const letters = ["a", "b", "c"];
// executes as
"a" === "b" // not equal, next!
"b" === "c" // not equal, next!
"c" === undefined // not equal, next!
// all letters have been checked (for-loop is complete), return false
```

Now let's have a look at your code:

> ```
> for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
>   if (letters[i] === letters[i + 1]){
>     return true
>   } else{
>     return false
>   }
> }
> ```

The above code checks if a letter is the same as a consecutive letter. If it is equal, `true` is returned. If it is not equal, `false` is returned. **This means that the function is always going to return in the first iteration.** The other letters are never checked.

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "b", "c"];
// executes as
"a" === "b" // not equal, return false

const letters = ["a", "b", "c"];
// executes as
"a" === "b" // not equal, return false
```

`return` is a statement that marks the end of the function. Nothing (within the same function) will be executed after a `return` statement, therefore the second iteration of the for-loop will never be reached and other letters are never checked.