# Iterating through an arrays with a for loop in Javascript only returns first value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration

This loop only returns the first index of the array and stops there.

```
const numArr = [2,4,6,8,10];

const iterate = (array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        return array[i]
    }
};

console.log(iterate(numArr));
```

Comment: Yes, that's because the function returns and stops executing after you access the first value.

Comment: Right, `return` stops further execution of your function.  You should figure out what you are trying to do. If you want to log every item in the array, move your `console.log` to within the `for` loop instead of calling it just once on the result of the function call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714503/does-return-stop-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Using `return` will end the loop in the first iteration

try

```js
const numArr = [2,4,6,8,10];

const iterate = (array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i])
    }
};

iterate(numArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Take-Some-Bytes mentioned in his comment it is because of the return statement. In JavaScript functions will stop executing when a return statement is called.

In your case, you call the function, the function starts looping through the array, it starts at the first item, sees a return statement and stops execution of the function.

On another note: This iterate method seems a little boiler plate or re-inventing things that are already available.

For example, have you tried:

```
const numArr = [2,4,6,8,10];
numArr.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

The code above does the same thing as:

```
const numArr = [2,4,6,8,10];

const iterate = (array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i])
    }
};

iterate(numArr);
```