# Returning all objects within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm new to JavaScript and working on a personal program which creates car objects and stores them in an array, I am having issues with returning all array elements as only the first array element is returned.

```js
const carFactory = {
    _cars:[
        {
            make: 'default',
            model: 'default',
            year: 0,
        }
    ],

    get cars(){
        if(this._cars.length > 0 ){
            for(let i = 0; i < this._cars.length; i++){
                return `Car Make: ${this._cars[i].make} - Car Model: ${this._cars[i].model} Manufacture Year: ${this._cars[i].year}`;
                }
        }else{
            return `Please add car details`;
            }
    },

    addCar(carMake, carModel, carYear){
        this._cars.push({
            carMake,
            carModel,
            carYear
        })
    }
}

carFactory.addCar('Toyota', 'Corolla', 2003);

console.log(carFactory.cars);
```

Comment: what `get cars` is supposed to return? One big string? Array of strings?

Comment: You should learn how to [debug your code](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)

Comment: **Note 1** In addition to other answers and comments, the OP does not create a standard car object/item by the `addCar` method cause the object will be `{ carMake: 'Toyota', carModel: 'Corolla', carYear: '2003' }` instead of the expected standard model of `{ make: 'Toyota', model: 'Corolla', year: '2003' }`

Comment: [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714503)

Comment: **Note 2** `carFactory` should be renamed to something else since it is not a factory function but an object which serves as namespace for methods and a pseudo-private `_cars` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement inside the for loop only returns the first car object in the `_cars` array and terminates the loop. To return all cars, you can concatenate the car objects into a string and return it after the loop:

```js
const carFactory = {
    _cars:[
        {
            make: 'default',
            model: 'default',
            year: 0,
        }
    ],

    get cars(){
        if(this._cars.length > 0 ){
            let allCars = '';
            for(let i = 0; i < this._cars.length; i++){
                allCars += `Car Make: ${this._cars[i].make} - Car Model: ${this._cars[i].model} Manufacture Year: ${this._cars[i].year}\n`;
            }
            return allCars;
        }else{
            return `Please add car details`;
        }
    },

    addCar(carMake, carModel, carYear){
        this._cars.push({
            make: carMake,
            model: carModel,
            year: carYear
        })
    }
}

carFactory.addCar('Toyota', 'Corolla', 2003);

console.log(carFactory.cars);
```

**Output:**

```
Car Make: default - Car Model: default Manufacture Year: 0
Car Make: Toyota - Car Model: Corolla Manufacture Year: 2003
```

Comment: Thank you, realized I made a few rookie errors! just gonna keep practicing

Answer (score 3):

You have a `return` in your `for`, which will exit the loop at the first iteration:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this._cars.length; i++){
  return `Car Make: ${this._cars[i].make} - Car Model: ${this._cars[i].model} Manufacture Year: ${this._cars[i].year}`;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want an array in return then return an array. and addCar method need to have right name.

```js
const carFactory = {
    _cars: [
        {
            make: 'default',
            model: 'default',
            year: 0,
        }
    ],

    get cars() {
        if (this._cars.length > 0) {
            let allCars = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < this._cars.length; i++) {
                let c = `Car Make: ${this._cars[i].make} - Car Model: ${this._cars[i].model} Manufacture Year: ${this._cars[i].year}`;
                allCars.push(c)
            }
            return allCars
        } else {
            return `Please add car details`;
        }
    },

    addCar(make, model, year) {
        this._cars.push({
            make,
            model,
            year
        })
    }
}

carFactory.addCar('Toyota', 'Corolla', 2003);
console.log(carFactory.cars);
```