# for loop returns only elements where i = 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, next.js, return

I'm trying to return 3 divs (for now) with a for loop but I'm only getting the first one, could someone explain why doesn't this work and how to fix it.

This is my function

```
const Bracket = ({bracket}: Props) => {
  for (let i = 1; i<=3; i++) {
    return (
      <div>
      {bracket.filter(match => match.roundNumber <= i).map((match) => (
      <Match 
       key={match.id}
       id={match.id}
       players={match.players}
       matchNumber={match.matchNumber} 
       roundNumber={match.roundNumber}              
      />
      ))}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried just mapping all matches and it worked, but I didnt know how to then sort them into 3 different divs depending on roundNumber (I would greatly appreciate if someone could give me a quick explanation on how to do this for future reference)

Comment: `return` stops the execution of the current function.

Comment: A `return` in a loop returns *one* element and exits the loop, nay, the *entire function.* You'll want to return an *array*…

Comment: [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714503)

Comment: The reason you're only getting the first div is that you have a return statement inside the for loop, which causes the function to exit on the first iteration